# How to enable autocomplete for Laravel Resources in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-5.5

Laravel 5.5 has a new API Resources feature, and it nicely redirects calls to model attributes (like `$this->id`). I use `ide-helper:models` to generate phpdocs for models that type-hints all model attributes. However, this does not apply to a resource and I get "Field accessed via magic method" squigglies. Is there a way to point it to model's phpdoc without copying it?

Comment: Why would you ever have to get the properties of a resource in your PHP code? I think you are misunderstanding what API resources are meant for. An API ressource is meant to convert a model into a easy object to return to the HTTP response.

Comment: How am I supposed to convert properties without getting them? My toArray method looks like `return ['id' => $this->id, 'name' => $this->name];` and I have no autocompletion on $this properties

Comment: Ooh sorry. I misunderstood your question then. I added an answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the **@mixin**

Here is an example, If you want the properties/phpdocs from the *User model* in your *User Resource*, then do like this

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

/**
 * Class User
 *
 * @mixin \User
 * */
class User extends Resource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man! Just came across this today and wow! What a savior!